# What does it mean to execute a command with the input instead of the keyboard?

Tags: linux, redirect, command, stdout, stdin

I have an assignment to create I/O redirection with my codes, but I have no idea what the below line means:

```
$cmd1 < in.txt
executes cmd1, using in.txt as the source of input, instead of the keyboard.
```

Does it mean that I need to execute a command, say `ls`, using `in.txt` file? How can I do this with a text file, though?

FYI, the output redirection's explanation is below:

```
$cmd2 > output.txt
executes cmd2 and places the output to file out.txt
```

Comment: If you run `rev`, you can enter lines on the keyboard and the command will reverse them. If you have text in a file, you can run `rev < myfile.txt` to (in effect) auto-type in the contents of `myfile.txt` so you don't have to enter it via the keyboard

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.